# 2D Coordinates of point defined as fractions of rectangular sides. Rectangular is not parallel to X, Y axes

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates

I have a rectangular ABCD: (x1,y1)... (x4,y4).
AB is not necessarily parallel to any of the axis.

I need to find coordinates of a point inside of it, defined as portion of its sides:
alpha *AB, alpha*CD .
beta*BC, beta*DA.
where alpha and beta are between 0 and 1.

Is there as simple solution to it?

Comment: Calculate points of `alphaAB` etc as `(x1 + alphaAB*(x2-x1), y1 + alphaAB*(y2-y1)`, determine the equations for the two lines connecting the two alpha and the two beta points and solve for the point where those lines intersect.

Comment: [I forgot to use \ before *] Anyway, thank you, that is how I wanted to solve it, but I thought maybe there is simpler solution

Comment: How could it be any simpler?  All that is doing is mapping one coordinate system to another.  You should keep that pattern in your brain, because you'll use it over and over.